# Integrating Turnitin on my website

Tags: plagiarism-detection

I have embarked on creating an online freelance writing website which is required to have a plagiarism checking software. It should work like this:

1. The expert works on the clients assignment
2. The expert posts the completed assignment to the client through the website
3. Before the client receives the work, a plagiarism software checks the work for originality and if original, the work is posted. Otherwise, the work is not posted and the expert is given an opportunity to work on it again

Does Turnitin allow for such use and if so, how do I do the integration? If not,  what plagiarism software allows the above? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Copyleaks Plagiarism Detection](https://api.copyleaks.com/) REST API for doing those tasks.

They expose all the needed methods for submitting files to checks, track scanning progress and get comparison report. You can embed the report within IFrame inside your website.

You can automate the whole process via their API.

Also, you can use their SDK in the major programming languages (python, php, c#, ...).